# Proving a multivariate normal distribution gets the maximum entropy when mean and covariance are given

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, optimization, information-theory

I'm working on a homework question. The first part was:

*Given an unbounded one dimensional continuous random variable: $X\in\left(-\infty,\infty\right)$, that satisfies:$\left\langle X\right\rangle =\mu,\;\left\langle \left(X-\mu\right)^{2}\right\rangle =\sigma^{2}$ Show that the distribution that maximizes entropy is Gaussian $X\sim N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)$.*

I've solved this using Lagrange multipliers method. The next part is proving the same holds in the case of multivariate distributions.

*Generalize the previous part to a $k$ dimensional variable $X$ with given expectation value $\vec{\mu}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.*

I started the same way when I define the proper functional I wish to optimize:
$$ F\left[f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)\right]=H\left(X\right)+\lambda\left(1-\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)d\overline{x}\right)+\sum_{i\in\left[k\right]}\varGamma_{i}\left(\mu_{i}-\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}\overline{x}_{i}f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)d\overline{x}\right)+\sum_{i,j\in\left[k\right]}\Lambda_{ij}\left(\Sigma_{ij}-\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}\left(\mu_{i}-\overline{x}_{i}\right)\left(\mu_{j}-\overline{x}_{j}\right)f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)d\overline{x}\right)$$

After taking the functional derivative with regard to $f_X(\overline{x})$ and extracting the PDF, I get the following term with the Lagrange multipliers:
$$f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)=\exp\left(\lambda-1\right)\exp\left(-\Gamma\cdot\overline{x}-\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)^{T}\Lambda\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)\right)$$
Where $\Gamma(k\times 1),\Lambda (k\times k),\lambda(1\times 1)$ are the multipliers.
I wish to show that these multipliers must equal the correct terms for this PDF to be a multivariate Gaussian.

For some reason this is where I get stuck, I've tried various algebraic manipulations, but the term $\exp{(-\Gamma\cdot\overline{x})}$ keeps messing up my calculations.
I'm leaving out the constraints themselves since they are written within the optimization term, and they leave me in the mess with $\exp{(-\Gamma\cdot\overline{x})}$ when I try to solve the integrals.

I feel like I'm missing something.
Would really appreciate it!

##### Edit:

1. Badly enough the answers for this exercise just say - "yeah this looks gaussian, so we can find the parameters so it works out", albeit this isn't strictly a math course, I have a very hard time accepting this answer, so the question is highly relevant.
2. There might be an easier way to solve this via KL divergence, but since the first part of the question was required for the next part I would really like to see this through.

##### Another Edit:

I get the calculations needed, my main issue is with the fact that the constraint $$\sum_{i\in\left[k\right]}\varGamma_{i}\left(\mu_{i}-\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}\overline{x}_{i}f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)d\overline{x}\right)$$ is not needed, since when solving the equation I can assign $\Gamma=0$ and get the proper results. I would like a rigorous explanation why the mean is determined solely by the 3rd constraint.

Comment: Are you familiar with KL divergence? the typical proof uses the fact that the KL div. is non-negative.

Comment: I am familiar, I don't really understand how that would help me in this case. I think I've already done most of the heavylifting

Comment: Presumably you derived the form of $f$ via a stationary point calculation for a Lagrangian of the form $\mathcal{L}(f; \lambda, \Lambda, \Gamma)$. The thing you seem to be missing is that the first order condition requires stationarity w.r.t. $f$ _and_ the dual variables $(\lambda, \Lambda, \Gamma)$. If you work out the stationarity condition for the dual variables, you'll find that these precisely demand constraint satisfaction.

Comment: (contd.) Now, it remains to check that you can in fact choose $\lambda, \Lambda, \Gamma$ in such a way that $f(x; \lambda, \Lambda, \Gamma)$ satisfies the constraints (so that you can conclude that you have a valid solution). This should be obvious if you're familiar with the moments of a Gaussian: set $\Lambda = \Sigma^{-1}/2, \Gamma = \mu,$ and $\lambda$ appropriately to ensure normalisation.

Comment: Incidentally, the KL divergence proof mentioned above is nice in that it avoids all the calculus of variations: let $n$ be the density of a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ random vector. Then $D(f\|n) \ge 0$ works out exactly to $h(f) \le h(n),$ and of course, $n$ itself is a density that achirves equality.

Comment: I understood the idea with using the other constraints, something about the calculations themselves isn't working out, I can see that once I choose the correct terms the constraints work out (that is how they were constructed), I just don't see how the term $\Gamma \bar{x}$ disapears..

Comment: 1. I noticed an error in my earlier comment (should be $\Gamma = 0$). 2. Are you, in essence, asking how to work out things like $\int (x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\top \exp( -\Gamma^\top x + (x-\mu)^\top \Lambda (x-\mu))$ in terms of $\Gamma, \Lambda$ so that you can then solve the constraint equations for the dual variables?

Comment: If so, for 2., start by noting that if $\Lambda$ is not positive definite, then the integrand is not integrable. If $\Lambda$ _is_ positive definite, you can introduce its square root, and change variables to the form $\textrm{something}\cdot \int yy^\top \exp( - \langle a,y\rangle - \|y\|^2)$. Then complete the square and reduce to a standard Gaussian computation, the working out of which you can probably look up in standard textbooks.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 If I want $\Gamma=0$ it essentially means that this constraint is useless, this is what I don't really understand, since we need both mean and covariance to uniquely describe a multivariate normal distribution. Is there a hidden assumption in my constraint on the covariance that includes the mean?

Comment: I added an answer. I don't clearly see why $\Gamma = 0$ at the optimum though, it's indeed somewhat curious. In fact the correct form also arises if you dropped the mean constraints. One  thing that might be at play is that you're as such enforcing $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top] = \Sigma$ rather than $\mathrm{Cov}(X) = \Sigma$, and that if you did the latter, the dual variables for the mean enforcement and the covariance enforcement would interact (but its not obvious to me at all that doing so means you don't need mean enforcement).

Comment: Actually, wait: if you expand things out, the constraint $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top] = \Sigma$ is equivalent to enforcing that $\mathrm{Cov}(X) = \Sigma - (\mu- \mathbb{E}X)(\mu -\mathbb{E}X)^\top.$ Now, we know that differential entropy increases with covariance in the PSD order, and since $vv^\top$ is PSD, if $\mu \neq \mathbb{E}X,$ the covariance is strictly smaller than $\Sigma$. So if we leave $\mathbb{E}X$ floating, then the optimum choice must implicitly also enforce $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$ in order to make covariance (and hence differential entropy) as large as possible, which

Comment: (contd). means that the expectation constraint is not needed _if_ you're explicitly enforcing that $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top] = \Sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I **first** provide a proof with required details based on the relative entropy method, and **then** I discuss how your **main issue** on dropping the expectation constraint when using the KKT method can be solved. Indeed, without the expectation constraint, the covariance of the distribution cannot be fixed, and you will have many other feasible normal densities satisfying the KKT conditions and both first and third constraints (see PS3 for more details).

---

Let $f_X \sim \mathcal N (\mu,\Sigma)$, for which $$\color{blue}{H(X)=\frac{1}{2} \log\left ((2\pi e)^n\det{\Sigma} \right)}.$$ Then, one can see that

$$\log f_{X}(x) = \underbrace{-\frac{1}{2} \log((2 \pi)^n\det{\Sigma})}_{\color{blue}{A:=-H(X)+\frac{1}{2} \log(e^n)}} -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu). \tag{1}$$

For any other density $f_Y$ with $\mathbb E (Y)=\mu$ and $\text{cov}(Y)=\Sigma$, the relative entropy is computed as

$$D_{\text{KL}}(f_Y\|f_X)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{Y}(x)\log \frac{f_{Y}(x)}{f_{X}(x)}\text{d}x=\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{Y}(x)\log f_{Y}(x)\text{d}x}_{-H(Y)}-\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{Y}(x)\log f_{X}(x)\text{d}x.  $$

From (1), the second integral can be written as

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{Y}(x)\log f_{X}(x)\text{d}x =A \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{Y}(x)\text{d}x}_{1}-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb R^n} \left( (x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) \right) f_{Y}(x)\text{d}x}_{\mathbb E \left ((Y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu) \right)=n}\\=A-\frac{1}{2}n=-H(X).$$

Hence,

$$D_{\text{KL}}(f_Y\|f_X)= -H(Y)+H(X)\ge 0 \equiv \color{blue}{H(X)}\ge H(Y), $$

which holds for every $Y$. This completes the proof.

---

**PS1:** Why $\color{blue}{D_{\text{KL}}(f_Y\|f_X) \ge 0}$?

$$D_{\text{KL}}(f_Y\|f_X)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{Y}(x)\log \frac{f_{Y}(x)}{f_{X}(x)}\text{d}x=\mathbb E \left (\log \frac{f_{Y}(Y)}{f_{X}(Y)} \right )=\mathbb E \left (-\log \frac{f_{X}(Y)}{f_{Y}(Y)} \right ) \ge -\log \mathbb E \left (\frac{f_{X}(X)}{f_{Y}(Y)} \right )=-\log \int_{\mathbb R^n} f_{X}(x)\text{d}x=-\log 1=0,$$

where the inequality follows from the [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) as $-\log$ is a convex function.

**PS2:** Why $\color{blue}{\mathbb E \left ((Y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu) \right)=n}$?

Let us define $Z=\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-\mu)$. Then,
$$\mathbb E (Z) =0.$$

$$\text{cov}(Z)=\mathbb E (ZZ^T)=\mathbb E (\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(Y-\mu)(Y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}})=\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}} \mathbb E (Y-\mu)(Y-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}  =I$$

Thus, all $Z_i, i=1,\dots,n$ are uncorrelated with mean $0$ and variance $1$, which gives

$$\mathbb E \left ((Y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu) \right)=\mathbb E \left (Z^TZ \right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E (Z_i^2)=n.$$

Note that $\Sigma$ is positive definite and symmetric, and it can be written as $$\Sigma=\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

**PS3:** **On your main issue**

Regarding your main issue in applying the KKT method:

> I get the calculations needed, my main issue is with the fact that the constraint $$\sum_{i\in\left[k\right]}\varGamma_{i}\left(\mu_{i}-\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}\overline{x}_{i}f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)d\overline{x}\right)$$ is not needed, since when solving the equation I can assign $\Gamma=0$ and get the proper results. I would like a rigorous explanation why the mean is determined solely by the 3rd constraint.

You already obtained only one of the possible candidate solutions (you found the most visible one). Without the expectation constraint, the problem has multiple KKT feasible solutions (densities). In fact, following your steps, you can find many other solutions other than what you already obtained. Let me show why there are other solutions without the expectation constraint in the following examples.

**Example 1.** The covariance constraint:

$$\mathbb E XX^T=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T \tag{1} $$

for any $ w \in [0,1]$, can be written as

$$\mathbb E (X-\sqrt{w}\mu)(X-\sqrt{w}\mu)^T=\Sigma+(1-w)\mu\mu^T,$$

which shows $X$ with

$$\text{cov}(X)=\Sigma+(1-w)\mu\mu^T, \mathbb E (X) =\sqrt{w}\mu$$

can be another feasible solution.

**Example 2.** To provide another example, note that $\Sigma$ can be decomposed as follows:

$$\Sigma=\sum_{j\in [n]}a_ja_j^T,$$

where $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are linearly independent. Thus, for any $a_i$ that $a_j,j \neq i, j\in[n]$ and $\mu$ are linearly independent, the covariance constraint (1) can be written as

$$\mathbb E (X-a_i)(X-a_i)^T=\sum_{j\in [n]: j \neq i} a_ia_i^T + \mu\mu^T.$$

This indicates that $X$ with $$\text{cov}(X)=\sum_{j\in [n]: j\neq i} a_ia_i^T + \mu\mu^T, \mathbb E (X) =a_ia_i^T$$

can be another solution.

Hence, in lack of $\mathbb E (X)=\mu$, following your steps, you can prove that any of the above distributions (and many other possible choices) with different $\text{cov}(X)$ and $\mathbb E (X)$ can be feasible KKT solutions, and picking the best among them needs solving another optimization problem discussed below.

When you drop the expectation constraint, the optimization problem reduces to the following semi-definite programming model with non-linear matrix inequalities:

$$\max \log \det W$$

subject to:

$$W=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T-yy^T \succeq 0, y\in\mathbb R^n,$$

which finds the normal density with maximum entropy in the set of normal distributions satisfying $\mathbb E XX^T=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T$ ($\mathbb E (X)=y$ and  $\text{cov}(X)=W$).
Solving the above problem seems difficult at first glance, but as the objective is increasing in $W$ with respect to the order $\succeq$, the upper bound is obtained by setting $y=0$. This means that the density  with maximum entropy with fixed second moments (1), $\color{blue}{\mathbb E XX^T=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T}$, is **a zero-mean normal distribution** with $$\mathbb E (X)=0, \text{cov}(X)=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T.$$

---

**If instead of** the constraint $$\mathbb E XX^T=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T,$$ the KKT conditions are written for $$\color{blue}{\mathbb E (X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T=\Sigma},$$ **as done in the OP**, and the expectation constraint is dropped, we obtain

$$\Sigma= \mathbb E (X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T=\mathbb E(X-\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)^T+(\mu_X-\mu)(\mu_X-\mu)^T \tag{2}.$$

Hence, by fixing $\mu_X \in \mathbb R^n$ to **any** value for which $$\Sigma- (\mu_X-\mu)(\mu_X-\mu)^T \succeq 0,$$ we can follow your procedure to show that the normal distribution
$$\mathcal N(\mu_X,\Sigma- (\mu_X-\mu)(\mu_X-\mu)^T)$$
is a feasible KKT solution. Now among all of the above KKT solutions, the one with $\mu_X=\mu$ achieves the maximum entropy because $\log\det A$ is an increasing function in $A$ with respect to $\succeq$. It is **interesting** that (unlike the case that the constraint $\mathbb E XX^T=\Sigma +\mu\mu^T$ is used) the optimal solution obtained by considering $\mathbb E (X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T=\Sigma$ is $\mathcal N(\mu,\Sigma)$ (differing from $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma+\mu\mu^T)$). However, if the expectation constraint is considered, for both cases we obtain only one feasible KKT point of $\mathcal N(\mu,\Sigma)$, which is also optimal. Now we can have the following concluding statement:

> If the first and third constraints in the OP are only considered, the nominal mean used in the third (tagged (2) in my answer) is determined as the mean of the optimal distribution because of its better performance among other candidate densities. This observation cannot be generalized by noting that if (2) is replaced with the **equivalent** constraint (1), the optimal density has zero mean.

Answer (score 5):

The proof of this can be made very simple. You want to minimize the following quantity
\begin{align}
H[\rho] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho \log \rho \, \mathrm{d}x \, ,
\end{align}
where $\rho$ is the p.d.f/law of the random variable $X$, subject to the constraint that $\rho$ has mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$. Denote by $N_{\Sigma,\mu}$ the corresponding Gaussian p.d.f. Let $\rho$ be a p.d.f which satisfies this constraint. We then have that
\begin{align}
H[\rho]= & \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho \log \frac{\rho}{N_{\Sigma,\mu}}  \, \mathrm{d}x +\int \rho \log N_{\Sigma,\mu} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho \log \frac{\rho}{N_{\Sigma,\mu}}  \, \mathrm{d}x -\frac{d}{2} -\frac 12 \log (2\pi)^d|\Sigma|  \qquad (*) \,.
\end{align}
The first term in (*) is the relative entropy between $
\rho$ and $N_{\Sigma,\mu}$ and the other terms are just fixed constants. The relative entropy (or what someone in the comments called the KL divergence) is always non-negative, so if you could make it zero you would have minimized the above quantity and you would be done. You can do this by choosing $\rho =N_{\Sigma,\mu}$.

Furthermore, here's a short proof that the relative entropy is non-negative. Using Jensen's inequality (since $x \log x$ is convex), we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho \log \frac{\rho}{N_{\Sigma,\mu}}  \, \mathrm{d}x = &\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{\rho}{N_{\Sigma,\mu}} \log \left(\frac{\rho}{N_{\Sigma,\mu}} \right) N_{\Sigma,\mu}   \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
\geq & 1 \cdot \log 1 =0   \, .
\end{align}

As a reference, look at Proposition 9.12 of the following book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4286-4. It contains the result you want but in more generality. Just a note: the authors of this book are trying the maximize the entropy because they have flipped its sign (this is the physicist definition of entropy).

Comment: @Amir I am not sure what you mean. I have labelled the equation to clarify things. The first term on the RHS of (*) is the relative entropy which is minimized by choosing $\rho$ to be the Gaussian while the second term is a constant which is the same for all pdfs satisfying the constraint and so can be disregarded.  Your comment that the first term is zero for any pdf satisfying the constraints is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but that is obvious.  $\Sigma$ is a fixed given matrix and so its determinant is a fixed constant. Also $d$ and $2 \pi$ are constants. If what you mean is that I have not explained how I landed up at that expression, yes that is true,  but I assume the OP can do that themselves as it just involves taking the log of an exponential and multiplying two matrices.

Comment: This is great, but I specificly asked for a solution that doesn't include KL-div since this doesn't match the first part of the exercise.

Comment: @Nadav Yes, of course I understand. I just thought it may be of general interest. Just out curiosity, when you say doesn't match the first part I guess you mean since you used Lagrange multipliers for the first part you want to use it for second part as well? Because in principle you could do both parts using the approach of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's compute the constrained functionals in terms of the dual variables, which might clarify things. The idea is almost completely illustrated via the computations for

$$ A(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) = \exp(\lambda-1) \int \exp( -\Gamma^\top x - (x-\mu)^\top \Lambda (x-\mu) )\mathrm{d}x. $$

Of course, this only makes sense if $\Lambda$ is positive definite, since otherwise the exponential blows up over the integration domain. If $\Lambda$ is positive definite, then there exists a positive definite matrix $\Lambda^{1/2}$ such that $(\Lambda^{1/2})^2 = \Lambda$. Substitute $x = \Lambda^{-1/2}y + \mu$ to get

$$ A \cdot \exp(1-\lambda) =\exp(-\Gamma^\top \mu) \int (\det \Lambda^{-1/2}) \exp( -\Gamma^\top \Lambda^{-1/2} y - y^\top y)\mathrm{d}y.$$ Let me write $v = -\Lambda^{-1/2} \Gamma/2$. Then we have \begin{align} A \cdot \exp(1-\lambda) \exp(\Gamma^\top \mu) \sqrt{\det \Lambda} &= \int \exp( 2v^\top y - y^\top y)\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \int \exp( - (y-v)^\top (y-v) + \|v\|^2)\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \exp(\|v\|)^2 \int \exp(-\|z\|^2)\mathrm{d}z\\
&= (\pi)^{k/2} \exp(\|v\|^2),\end{align} where I've used the substitution $y = z + v$ and the final equality is just the Gaussian integral.
Translating everything back, we get $$ A(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) = (\pi)^{k/2} \exp(\lambda - 1 - \Gamma^\top \mu + \|\Lambda^{-1/2} \Gamma\|^2/4) (\det \Lambda)^{-1/2}. $$

Now similarly define $$ B(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) := \exp(\lambda-1) \int x\exp( -\Gamma^\top x - (x-\mu)^\top \Lambda (x-\mu) )\mathrm{d}x. $$

Then carrying out exactly the same manipulations, we will end up at $$B(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) = A(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) \cdot \int (\pi)^{-k/2} (\Lambda^{-1/2} y + \mu) \exp(- \|y - \Lambda^{-1/2}\Gamma/2\|^2 ) \mathrm{d}y\\ = A(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) \cdot (\mu + \Lambda^{-1}\Gamma/2).  $$

Further, for $$ C(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) :=  \exp(\lambda-1) \int (x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\top \exp( -\Gamma^\top x - (x-\mu)^\top \Lambda (x-\mu) )\mathrm{d}x, $$

we end up with $$C =  A(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) \int (\pi)^{-k/2} \Lambda^{-1/2} yy^\top \Lambda^{-1/2} \exp( - \|y - \Lambda^{-1/2} \Gamma/2\|^2) \mathrm{d}y \\ = A(\lambda, \Gamma, \Lambda) \left(\Lambda^{-1}/2 +\Lambda^{-1} \Gamma \Gamma^\top \Lambda^{-1}/4  \right),$$ where I've used the usual decomposition $\mathrm{Cov}(X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^\top] -\mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[X]^\top.$

---

Now, the constraints are that $A = 1, B = \mu, C = \Sigma.$ Plugging $A = 1$ into $B,C$, this yields $$ \mu + \Lambda^{-1} \Gamma/2 = \mu, \Lambda^{-1}/2 + \Lambda^{-1} \Gamma \Gamma^\top \Lambda^{-1}/4 = \Sigma,$$ and the solution over positive definite $\Lambda$ is exactly $\Gamma = 0, \Lambda = \Sigma^{-1}/2$ as expected. This in turn gives $$ A(\lambda, 0, \Sigma^{-1}/2) = \pi^{k/2}\exp(\lambda - 1) (\det (\Sigma^{-1}/2)^{-1} = \exp(\lambda - 1) \cdot (2\pi)^{k/2} \det \Sigma,$$ and enforcing that this is $1$ yields the appropriate normalisation for the Gaussian.

Comment: This was down voted sans comment, I'd appreciate a heads up if you see errors.

Answer (score 2):

'"Badly enough the answers for this exercise just say - "yeah this looks gaussian, so we can find the parameters so it works out"' -- this is absolutely a correct and rigorous thing to say, though it can maybe be worded/explained better. If you have a probability distribution of the form $$f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)=\exp\left(\lambda-1\right)\exp\left(-\Gamma\cdot\overline{x}-\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)^{T}\Lambda\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)\right)$$

or, more generally,

$$f_{X}\left(\overline{x}\right)=C\exp\left(-\vec{u}\cdot\overline{x}-\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)^{T}\Lambda\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)\right)$$

that satisfies:$\left\langle \vec{X}\right\rangle =\vec{\mu},\;\left\langle \left(\vec{X}-\vec{\mu}\right)^{2}\right\rangle =\Sigma$, then it **is** the Gaussian with mean $\vec{\mu}$ and covariance $\Sigma$.

The point is that  $\left(-\vec{u}\cdot\overline{x}-\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)^{T}\Lambda\left(\vec{\mu}-\overline{x}\right)\right)$ is a (affine, or inhomogeneous) quadratic form, so in order for this to be a distribution $\Lambda$ has to be positive definite, and then your distribution is a multivariate Gaussian. Since it is a distribution, $C$ must take the unique value that normalizes the total integral of the density to 1. Furthermore, a Gaussian is uniquely specified by its mean vector and covariance matrix. So if you know that your Gaussian has mean $\vec{\mu}$ and variance  $\Sigma$ then it must be the $N(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma)$. (In your case this implies $\Lambda = \Sigma/2$ and $\Gamma=\vec{0}$, but that's kind off beside the point.)

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer for the OP question. If  one has density that has the form $ \alpha \exp g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a general quadratic form, then the form must be positive definite and the density is a multivariate gaussian.