Discrete analogue of entropy-variance inequality
It is well-known that the normal distribution maximizes entropy among all probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with fixed mean and covariance. Since the entropy of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ is $\frac{1}{2}\big( n + \log((2\pi)^n \det \Sigma)\big)$, this leads to the inequality $$
h(X) \leq \frac{1}{2}\big( n + \log((2\pi)^n \det \Sigma)\big)
$$ for any continuous random variable $X$ with covariance $\Sigma$.
I want to know if there is a discrete analogue of this inequality. Namely, for a discrete random variable $X$ supported on a finite set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, is there an inequality of the form $$
h(X) \leq C(n,\mathrm{Cov}[X])
$$ where $C$ is a function of $n$ and the covariance matrix of $X$? Equivalently, what is the entropy of the maximum entropy distribution supported on a finite set $S$ with fixed mean and covariance?

Fixing mean and variance is equivalent to fixing the first and second moment. So, if the discrete distribution is supported on a countable set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$, then Lagrange multiplier tells that the maximum entropy distribution $(p(x))_{x\in E}$ takes the form $$p(x)\propto e^{-\alpha x-\beta x^2}$$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

@SangchulLee Thanks for the reply. I know that formulation however it is not really possible to solve $\alpha,\beta$ from the mean and covariance. The point is, I am not trying to compute the distribution itself but only its entropy so I was wondering if there is a solution for that.

A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4874283/1231520

@Amir It is related but unfortunately the discrete and the continuous case seem to differ immensely.
